# Proving $\frac{d}{dx}{x\over\sqrt{x^2+2}}$ = $ 2 \over (x^2+2)^{3/2}$ from definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Using the definition of derivative, prove that $\displaystyle {\frac{d}{dx}{x\over{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}= {2 \over{ (x^2+2)^{3/2}}}}$.

What I have done:

$\lim_{h\to 0}$ ${f(x+h) - f(x)} \over h$

= $\lim_{h\to 0}$${x+h} \over { h\sqrt {(x+h)^2 + 2}}$ $-$ $\lim_{h\to 0}$$x \over { h\sqrt{x^2 + 2}}$

= $\lim_{h\to 0}$ $x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2} \over h(x+h)^2+2h$ $+$ $\lim_{h\to 0}$$\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2} \over {(x+h)^2+2}$ $-$ $\lim_{h\to 0}$$x\sqrt{x^2+2} \over h(x^2+2)$

And I'm stuck. I can't seem to prove it using the derivative definition. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't write the second line as though you can split up the limit (you can't, since both limits fail to exist). Also, should the first term in the title have denominator $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}$?

Comment: This is unprovable, because it's not true

Comment: It's not true. Maybe you mean $\frac{d}{dX}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $\frac{d}{dx}{x\over\sqrt{(x^2+2)}}$ = $ 2 \over (x^2+2)^{3/2}$

Sorry for the typo error. I will try to edit the question label.

Comment: The bit about proving this from the definition of derivative is important context (since proving it via the power rule and the quotient rule is straightforward) so I've added that to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can't split the limit like you attempted to: it's no true that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)}{h}-
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)}{h}
$$
because the two limits on the right hand side are infinite (and of different sign from the left and from the right).

---

The ratio you have to compute the limit of is
$$
\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{x+h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}\right)
=
\frac{(x+h)\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}}
  {h\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\,\sqrt{x^2+2}}
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{(x+h)^2(x^2+2)-x^2((x+h)^2+2)}
{h\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\,\sqrt{x^2+2}
 \bigl((x+h)\sqrt{x^2+2}+x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\bigr)}
$$
Expand the numerator:
$$
x^4+2hx^3+h^2x^2+2x^2+4hx+4h^2
-x^4-2hx^3-h^2x^2-2x^2=4h(x+h)
$$
Thus you have to compute
$$
\lim_{h\to0}
\frac{4(x+h)}
{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\,\sqrt{x^2+2}
 \bigl((x+h)\sqrt{x^2+2}+x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+2}\bigr)}
$$
and this is easy.

---

Of course, the quotient rule is much easier: recall that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+2}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}
$$
so the derivative of your function is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}{x^2+2}
$$
and the algebra is very easy.